# App closes shortly after launching in ios but android works fine?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3

I am having a problem with ios when i launch the app, it shows the splash screen then the app just closes itself. While on android it works fine.

> right now this is my config:

```
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
```

> my plugin list is below:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.2 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.4.3 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

> my ionic info is below:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v6.12.0
npm        : 3.10.10 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

I have also try using Cordova Platforms 4.4.0 and 4.5.1 but getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to see your Config.xml, I can only speculate that you are attempting to use a permission that is being denied in Xcode, due to a missing permission string.

Are you using the Camera, Microphone, Photo library or Location services?

Typically XCode will output an error message on the log when the app crashes. In most instances that I've encountered, it's due to a missing plist.info string.

Here's a sample of my config.xml that includes the usage descriptions:

```
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
        <string>To take photos.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
        <string>To choose photos.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription">
        <string>To record videos.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="Use for video and audio messages">
        <string>To record videos.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for...</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for...</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for...</string>
    </edit-config>
```

Add those to the bottom of your config.xml, below the  tag, and see what happens now.